# Change the HTML of a div on mouseover of another element

Tags: jquery, html

I have something like this:

```
<div class="baloon">
    <div class="baloon-title">Chage title</div>
    <div class="baloon-desc">Change description</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1" title="clients" desc="Access all your client details and their history of stays.">
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->BaseUrl ?>/img/icons/1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="span1" title="clients2" desc="Access2 all your client details and their history of stays.">
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->BaseUrl ?>/img/icons/2.png">
    </div>
```

and I have jquery function like this:

```
$('.span1').mouseover(function(){
    title = $(this).attr("title");
    desc = $(this).attr("desc");
    $('.baloon-title').html(title);
    $('.baloon-desc').html(desc);
});
```

I want to change content of div `baloon-title` and `baloon-desc` on mouseover of `span1`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. Can you describe why you think you're doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code works, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWkTB/)

Comment: I reformatted your code and noticed that a closing div is missing for the row class. This could be an issue.

Comment: I don't get results...and Firebug doesn't show any error...

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4yDs3/) in chrome

Comment: I see it's working fine, and now I'm more confused...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've shown will work *if* you have included a version of jquery.js *and* you put your JS in a script block that appears after the divs in question or you put it in a document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.span1').mouseover(function(){
       title = $(this).attr("title");
       desc = $(this).attr("desc");
       $('.baloon-title').html(title);
       $('.baloon-desc').html(desc);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5w33G/

If you included the JS in a script element before the `'.span1'` div (without a document ready handler) then that div won't have been parsed yet when the JS code runs so jQuery won't find the div and thus won't bind the mouseover handler.

Comment: Good catch. Sounds like the lack of a `ready()` handler is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your script with jQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {

// your code here

});
```

it should work fine.